# What does "война из-за угла" mean?

Tags: значения

Что это такое "война из-за угла"?
Чем она отличается от герильи или партизанской войны?

**UPDATE #1:**
Выражение из книги для детей, в переводе с французского:

> Война из-за угла, это другая форма войны без больших сражений. Ее участники действуют скрытно, неожиданно атакуют или совершают покушения.

**UPDATE #2:**
I found the original edition in French, for which the word being used is *guérilla*. Obviously, *герилья* or *партизанская война* would have been less ambiguous.

Comment: I've added it in the question.

Comment: Интересно было бы посмотреть какой термин используется во французском издании. Возможно переводчик пошел на поводу у оригинала.

Comment: Мне тоже. Попробую найти французское издание.

Comment: @Artemix, нашел термин: *guérilla*.

Comment: Выражение "это другая форма войны" тоже какое-то неестественное. Похоже переводчик не сильно старался. В русском корпусе "это другая форма" встречается только один раз: "Познание Церкви ― это другая форма знания, которое достигается опытом общения с Богом."

Comment: Спасибо, теперь мне все ясно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примеры:

*"Беспилотники: война из-за угла. ... На этом фоне немецкие СМИ сообщили о возможном использовании Пентагоном своих баз в Германии для нанесения ракетных ударов с боевых беспилотных летательных аппаратов по «не афишируемым целям» в суверенных странах."*
  (http://newsradio.com.ua/rus/2013_06_07/Bespilotniki-vojna-iz-za-ugla/)

*"Гибридная война - война из-за угла и подворотни"* (http://ehorussia.com/new/node/9092)

*"Война ПОДЛАЯ! война ИСПОДТИШКА! война ИЗ-ЗА УГЛА!"* (http://www.charter97.org/en/news/2014/5/24/99815/comments/) (по мнению автора, Россия засылает войска в/на Украину, публично заявляя о своей непричастности)

Вывод: война из-за угла - это подлая война исподтишка: страна фактически ведёт военные действия против другой страны, но или отрицает это, или пострадавшая страна не знает, кто ведёт против неё военные действия, а то и вообще не знает о военных действиях.

Answer (score 3):

Никогда не слышал выражения `война из-за угла`. Мне кажется, здесь подразумевается выражение `удар из-за угла` — то есть, "неожиданное нападение", с дополнительной негативной коннотацией "подлое". Выражение `война из-за угла` без контекста понять трудно, но, скорее всего, имеется в виду война, начатая неожиданно, воспринимаемая говорящим как подлая.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I thought it was a well known expression, but it's obviously not.